# Domain model vs Entity FW: Is this a case when splitting in a persistence model is usefull?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, domain-driven-design

In a DDD approach, I have a Domain Model (DM), with a rich behaviour. Suppose I have a root entity, called `Order` and relative `LineOrder`. The exposed collection of `LineOrder` need to be a `IReadOnlyCollection` since none can alter the collection arbitrarily. In code:

```
public class Order : AggregateRoot {
    // fields
    private List<LineOrder> lineOrder;

    // ctors
    private Order() {
        this.lineOrder = new List<LineOrder>();
        // other initializations
    }

    // properties
    public IReadOnlyCollection<LineOrder> LineOrder {
        get
        {
            return lineOrder.AsReadOnly();
        }
    }

    // behaviours  
}
```

So far, so good. But when I want to persist this domain I have some technology restrictions imposed by Entity Framework (a key is needed even if I have a value object, a parameterless constructor and so on) that is not a perfect match with a DDD approach.
Another limitation that I have is:

```
public class OrderConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Order>
{
    public OrderConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("Order");
        HasMany<LineOrder>(m => m.LineOrder); // Exception: Cannot convert from IReadOnlyCollection to ICollection
    }
}
```

I cannot cast `IReadOnlyCollection` to `ICollection` (incidentally, if `LineOrder` was an `ICollection` everything was OK!).

For the reasons I have expressed above: could be usefull in this case create a Persistence Model (with belonging cons: mapping DM/PM and viceversa)?

Are there an alternative? And, above all: are there an alternative that well fit a DDD approach?

Comment: For me it's a bit strange to use IReadOnlyCollection. As I remember IReadOnlyCollection doesn't save you from editing elements inside. Thus I can do something like readOnlyCollection.First().Amount = 100. So, it is not very good too. Don't you want to use IList instead of IReadOnlyCollection and just copy lineOrder? Conceptually there are another two solutions: 1) return full copy of list including LineOrder items, 2) remove some accessors and use another public method with custom LineOrder representation

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried declaring the `LineOrder` collection as `protected`? This way EF has access but consumers do not.

```
// properties
protected ICollection<LineOrder> LineOrder { get; set; }
```

You can then expose this collection in a read-only manner to the end user with:

```
public IReadOnlyCollection<LineOrder> ReadOnlyLineOrder
{
    get
    {
        return LineOrder.ToList().AsReadOnly();
    }
}
```

Comment: IMO this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Yes, it works, but this has several side effects:
i) I don't want to hide `LineOrder` to the consumer, instead I want to hide `lineOrder`
ii) use `ICollection` instead of `IReadOnlyCollection` will cause runtime error if `Add` is invoked (where `IReadOnlyCollection` will produce a compile time error, and that is better)

Comment: Apologies for not being more complete. I will edit the answer to improve the clarity.

Comment: Domain and configuration are in two different class, and doesn't have inheritance relationships :\

Comment: With this approach, your EF mapping/configuration shouldn't need to change.

Comment: I mean `OrderConfiguration` doesn't have any inheritance relationship with `Order` class, so protecting the `ICollection` automatically hides `LineOrder` from the configuration...

Comment: The configuration line in OrderConfiguration shouldn't be necessary as the EF convention should define the relationship automatically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60626/discussion-between-marianoc84-and-rob-epstein).